# Unity 5.1 Distorted image after download from web

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, distortion

When I load my png after compressing with tiny png, they get distorted( all purple and transparent)
http://s22.postimg.org/b39g0bhn5/Screen_Shot_2015_06_28_at_10_39_50_AM.png

the background for example should be blue

http://postimg.org/image/fez234o6d/

this only happens when i use pictures that got compressed by tinypng.com
and only after i updated to unity 5.1.
Im downloading the image with WWW class and loading texture using Texture2D.
is this problem known to anyone?

Comment: Have you come up with any solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I was able to solve it using the following code

```
    mat.mainTexture = new Texture2D(32, 32, TextureFormat.DXT5, false);
    Texture2D newTexture  = new Texture2D(32, 32, TextureFormat.DXT5, false);
    WWW stringWWW = new WWW(texture1URL);

    yield return stringWWW;
    if(stringWWW.error == null)
    {
        stringWWW.LoadImageIntoTexture(newTexture);
        mat.mainTexture = newTexture;
    }
```

The key seemed to be using DXT5 as the texture format, and using the method LoadImageIntoTexture(...);